# prevent dropdown from changing knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a grid template with the add, remove and binding, much like the one in the tutorials.

In this template http://jsfiddle.net/mouseoctopus/Qy736/, I'd like to make it so that each of the dropdowns carries a unique value - ie. no repetition of the value - so I'm trying to add logic into the change block.

If I was using jquery, to handle events I might try to bind to the change and determine if the value is currently selected by another dropdown, and prevent default if it happened.

Is this same behavior possible using knockout?

My event is firing, but I am unable to prevent default.

The relevant code is below

HTML

```
   <td><select data-bind="options: $root.PhoneTypes, value: name, optionsText:'name',
            event: { change: $root.changeType}" ></select></td>
```

View

```
  self.changeType = function(data, event){
      return false;
  };
```

see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mouseoctopus/Qy736/  for the live example

I'm super newb to knockout <2 days, so I'm likely to be not understanding the docs, etc. On this page 
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html , it does mention adding the property changeBubble: false, but this didnt really seem to help.

Q: Can I / how can I prevent the select change from happening conditionally (so that I can insert custom validation on this behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy736/5/)

I don't know of anyway to stop the event as you desire. However, you can store the previous value and then change back if the user attempts to choose a previously chosen type:

```
function PhoneNumber(type, number, comment) {
    var self = this;

    self._type = type;    
    self.type = ko.observable(type);
    self.number = number;
    self.comment = comment;
}

function PhoneNumbersViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.subTitle = ko.observable("Call Me Maybe");

    self.PhoneTypes = [
        { name: "Fax" },
        { name: "Home" },
        { name: "Mobile" },
        { name: "Work" }
    ];    

    self.phoneNumbers = ko.observableArray([
        new PhoneNumber(self.PhoneTypes[0], "500-555-5555", "Phoney")
    ]);

    self.addPhoneNumber = function() {
        self.phoneNumbers.push(new PhoneNumber(self.PhoneTypes[0], "", ""));
    }

    self.removePhoneNumber = function(number) {
        self.phoneNumbers.remove(number);
    }

    self.clearSubtitle = function(){ this.subTitle(""); }

    self.changeType = function(data, event){
        if(self.phoneNumbers().some(function(number) {
            return number != data && number.type().name == data.type().name;
        })) {
            data.type(this._type);
        } else {
            this._type = data.type();
        }
    };
}
```

This doesn't fix the issue of the new item being set to a type that may already be chosen...but that's not what you were asking.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're interested, but I came up with an alternate solution to my problem - I remove the items that shouldn't be selected from the dropdown. Its a bit complex. see http://jsfiddle.net/mouseoctopus/2552K/